# PrimeNg p-menubar change custom icon by ng-template

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I'm trying to change p-menubar icon (pi-chevron-down) to my own.

I wish to use code:

```
            <ng-template pTemplate="dropdownicon">
              <my-icon></my-icon>
            </ng-template>
```

In other primeNg components it's working but not in p-menubar. How can I do it?